# Scanned document on Sonoma not modifiable

Tags: macos, preview, scanning

My usual workflow when I scan a text document is to correct colors and play with contract to reduce their file size. However, since I upgraded to Sonoma, I find that whatever image I scan, to whatever format (tried png and jpeg so far) end up creating files that I am totally unable to save after modification, or save as another name, from the Preview app of macOS.

I get this message on Save As:

```
The document “scan.png” could not be saved as “scan-a”.
```

And this when I play with the colors and Save:

```
The document “scan.png” could not be saved.
```

If anyone knows a fix for this, I would be most grateful, as fixing colors of scanned PNG images reduces their size from 20 MiB to between 1 and 2 MiB. It also helps removing scan artifacts by playing with the contrast.

There seem to be additional macOS permissions happening here (judging from the `@` in the permissions), but I don't know much more. In the *Inspect* window for the file, I don't see it being *Locked* and the listed privileges for my user are *Read & Write*.

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adeynack  staff    15M Oct 16 22:37 scan.png
-rw-r--r--  1 adeynack  staff     4B Oct 16 22:40 test.txt
```

## EDIT / Additional Info

#### Software Used

The software used for scanning the *Image Capture*, included in *macOS*.

#### More Detailed `ls`

The result of `ls -lae@` is as following.

```
total 29904
drwxr-xr-x  5 adeynack  staff       160 Oct 16 22:40 .
drwx------+ 9 adeynack  staff       288 May 22 21:33 ..
 0: group:everyone deny delete
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adeynack  staff      6148 Oct 16 22:41 .DS_Store
    com.apple.FinderInfo          32
-rw-r--r--@ 1 adeynack  staff  15296080 Oct 16 22:37 scan.png
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS         16
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_djebsaob4taaoilt6jtfvis3ne       121
    com.apple.quarantine          22
-rw-r--r--  1 adeynack  staff         4 Oct 16 22:40 test.txt
```

Funny, this `quarantine` metadata that we see there . However, even after removing it...

```bash
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine scan.png
```

... I still cannot *Save* / *Save As* the file.

And the moment I try again to open it in *Preview* and save it, the `quarantine` metadata comes back.

#### Alternatives Tried

The software saves automatically in `~/Pictures/Scan`. I tried copying the file over to `~/Downloads` and it had the same effect. I tried *Duplicate*-ing the file from *Finder* and it still had the same behavior.

Comment: What software/hardware are you scanning with?

Comment: In case the issue is privileges, what is the output of `ls -lae@` and the same for the parent folder?

Comment: What is the filepath of the original scan? Have you tried saving somewhere like your Desktop?

Comment: @IconDaemon Answered in the EDIT section I just added to the post

Comment: @benwiggy Answered in the EDIT section I just added to the post

Comment: @Gilby Answered in the EDIT section I just added to the post

Comment: Hmm. And this is just a normal text document? Black & White? Have you tried scanning in greyscale? Have you tried saving as a PDF? You can change the destination in Image Capture. What happens then?

Comment: @benwiggy With a PDF, I cannot change the color balance. ‍♂️

Comment: @benwiggy: Otherwise, that `scan.png` file is a blank scan (no document in scanner, makes no difference with real scans). I will try with different color settings...